# SQL Server : update trigger with 'if' condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to implement a SQL Server trigger to update a row in table B when update in table A with a if condition.

**table A:**

```
id_AA
status
desc1
desc2
```

**table B:**

```
id_BA
desc3
desc4
```

The logic is like this:

```
if user update table A set status == success
update B: when id_BA == id_AA
set desc3 = desc1
desc4 = desc2
```

Comment: And what have you tried up to now?

Comment: Does this give any errors or just doesn't fire?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% clear on your logic, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TableA_Update 
ON dbo.TableA
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE  TableB
    SET     Desc3 = i.Desc1,
            Desc4 = i.Desc2
    FROM    TableB b
            INNER JOIN inserted i           
                ON i.ID_AA = b.ID_BA        -- MATCH CRITERIA IN QUESTION
                AND i.Status = 'success'    -- NEW STATUS IS "SUCCESS"
            INNER JOIN deleted d
                ON d.ID_AA = i.ID_AA
                AND d.Status != 'success'   -- PREVIOUS STATUS WAS NOT "SUCCESS"
END
```

**EDIT**

If there is not a corresponding row in `TableB` you may want to consider using `MERGE`

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TableA_Update 
ON dbo.TableA
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH Updated AS
    (   SELECT  i.ID_AA, i.Desc1, i.Desc2
        FROM    inserted i
                INNER JOIN deleted d
                    ON d.ID_AA = i.ID_AA
                    AND d.Status != 'success'   -- PREVIOUS STATUS WAS NOT "SUCCESS"
        WHERE   i.Status = 'success'
    )
    MERGE INTO TableB USING Updated ON ID_AA = ID_BA
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE
        SET Desc3 = Desc1,
            Desc4 = Desc2
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (ID_BA, Desc3, Desc4) VALUES (ID_AA, Desc1, Desc2);
END
```